# JQuery toggle UL visible on Load

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

After a lot of googling i figured how to use Jquery toggle. it seems to work fine. But on Loading first the 'ul' is Visible and hide if i click (so the toggle seems to work) i just dont know how to hide the ul on load and then show on click here is my code

jQuery(function($){

```
$('.cliackable').click(function(){ $(this).find('ul').toggle();});

$('.cliackable').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

}); // end function

```
                    <div id="navigation-prof">

                        <ul class="sf-menu-prof"  >

                            <li style="color:#fff;" class="cliackable">

                              <?php echo get_avatar( $userdata->ID, 35 );?>

                                <ul>
                                        <div style="padding:15px 0px 0px 15px; ">
                                            <div class="left" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                                                <?php echo get_avatar( $userdata->ID, 75 );?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="right" style="align:left">
                                                <a href="" class="login-head-font" style="text-align:left"><?php echo  $userdata->user_firstname .' ' . $userdata->user_lastname ;?></a>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    <div style="width:100%;">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="login-head-font" href="http://thecampustree.com/your-profile">Profile</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="login-head-font" href="http://thecampustree.com/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
                                    </li>   
                                    </div>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>


                    </div>
```

CSS>>

```
 #navigation-prof {width:35px; border-left:1px solid #999;padding:5px; border-right:1px solid #999;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;}
 #navigation-prof  .sf-menu-prof ul li ul{display:none;}
 #navigation-prof  .sf-menu-prof ul{ background:#e73420; width:250px; margin:0px 0px 0px -200px;}
 #navigation-prof  .sf-menu-prof li li{background:#e73420;border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); width: 235px; clear:both; padding:5px 0px 5px 15px; color:#fff;}
 #navigation-prof  .sf-menu-prof li li a {width: 235px; padding:5px 100px 5px 15px; color:#fff;}
```

////I AM A NEWBEI//// THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide it on document ready event:

```
$('.cliackable ul').hide();
```

or hide it using CSS:

```
#navigation-prof .sf-menu-prof li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks i think i was just using the wrong css. i used ul li ul as suggested by someone. but yours worked perfectly :)

Comment: thanx, one more query i want the ul to hide when clicked anywhere outside the ul basically what google suggests is on body click or something